# corr_matrix=df_cat.corr(method="pearson") sns.heatmap(corr_matrix,annot=True) plt.title('correlation matrix for numerical features')

Tags: python

Error is coming in below code

```
  corr_matrix=df_cat.corr(method="pearson")
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix,annot=True)
plt.title('correlation matrix for   numerical features')
```

Graph should appear of correlation

Comment: Look up how to write a useful stack overflow post. It will include that you need to state what you want to achieve, the problem, and what you've tried (so far) to solve it. It's difficult to help you with such little information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the full error traceback message. You can [edit] the question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) if you want more tips.